# How can I add SVN properties for WSDL and XSD which JAX-WS RI generate?

Tags: java, web-services, svn, wsdl, jax-ws

I have two web service. The first web service has WSDL and XSD in project. I added following SVN properties to WSDL:

```
<wsdl:documentation>
    $Revision:$
    $Date: $
</wsdl:documentation>
```

and It is working. Now I want to add these SVN properties for second web service. Here is POJO:

```
@WebService
@Stateless(mappedName = "ejb", name = "SecondService")
public class SecondService implements SecondServiceRemote, SecondServiceLocal {
(...)
}
```

It doesn't has WSDL and XSD in project. My WebLogic server published SecondService's XSD and WSDL. Published and generated by JAX-WS RI. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5.

My question is : How can I add SVN properties for my SecondService's XSD and WSDL?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

you can't do it, because svn:keywords is property of versioned file, existing in repository, translated into *some value* only on checkout into Working Copy

**Longer answer**

Because in secod case WSDL is generated by POJO and changed WSDL means "something was changed in POJO" you can use **`$Revision$` and `$Date$` values of POJO** inside `<wsdl:documentation>` node definition in POJO